# How to turn current job in background?

Tags: command-line

I've ssh-ed to my ubuntu 15 server box.

And I run apt-get xxx. It takes too long to download, and I don't want to stop it.

How can I turn this job in background just like from the start I run it with "&"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can background a process by typing `C-z`, at that point, the process is suspended and doesn't do anything other than wait. Then execute `bg` to allow the process to continue in the background.

`jobs` will list all the process running/waiting in the background.

```
testarossa :: ~ % jobs                            
[1]  + suspended  sudo apt-get update
```

To bring it back to the foreground you can just execute `fg`. In case you have many processes running in the background you can specify which one to bring to the foreground (or continue in the background) by specifying the process id (e.g., `[1]` in the above example). So given the above example, `bg 1` and `bg` are equivalent. Note that this is *not* the pid!

Using a terminal multiplexer like `screen` and `tmux` would have prevented this. Might want to check those out.

#### Example

```
testarossa :: ~ % sudo apt-get update                                                                                            1 ↵
[sudo] password for christophe: 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:1 https://get.docker.com docker InRelease                                  
100% [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14)] [^Z
[1]  + 16963 suspended  sudo apt-get update
testarossa :: ~ % bg                                                                                                            20 ↵
[1]  + 16963 continued  sudo apt-get update
```

Do mind that output from the process appears on your terminal! You can, however, just do normal stuff on the commandline as you wish.

Comment: will it keep running in the background ? or just "pause/stop" ?

Comment: If you only execute `C-z` it will pause. If you execute `bg` afterwards as well, it will continue.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer: I'd would rephrase your answer (even though you already precise the correction) : "You first suspend the foreground job by pressing `C-z`, [at that point, the process is suspended and doesn't do anything other than wait], and then you allow it to continue running in the background by typing `bg`. `jobs` will show you the backgrounded jobs. To bring one in the foreground again (for example, to then be able to stop it), you type:  `fg %n`, n being the job's number (not its pid!). "

Comment: I have extended the answer as per your comment. Thank you!