# "Text Editor" is not responding

Tags: 20.04, java, gnome-terminal, gedit

1. ubuntu 20.04 LTS
2. shell version - GNOME Shell 3.36.9
3. gedit version - gedit - Version 3.36.2

When I click 'wait' nothing happened:

[image: Gedit ScreenShot]

What I did:

I run gedit from termial and its not come back to my home path. So I input **ctrl+Z**.

[image: Terminal ScreenShot]

Comment: When you hit Ctrl+Z did the shell not respond with something like `[1]+  Stopped        gedit` ?

Comment: yes it says [1]+  Stopped  gedit .I did it because I have not another option.

Comment: ... so tell the shell to resume the job in the background, using `bg 1`

Comment: See for example [How to turn current job in background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726293/how-to-turn-current-job-in-background)

Comment: Nope. It's not working.I want to come back to my home path to compile my java program.

Comment: What happens *before* you hit Ctrl+Z. Is gedit already frozen then? Does it also happen with a different file? If no, then you are sure it is due to the file, and the problem can be more focused from the start.

Comment: when i restarted laptop it was  working.By the way thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in the terminal, you suspended the running process, in this case the editor `gedit`. If you then attempt to close it, you get the screen you see because the app is not responding - *you* made it not responsive because you suspended it.

Type `bg` to send the suspended foreground process to the background and resume it. The command prompt will be released for you to enter another command, and gedit will continue to run.

To immediately send the process to the background while you launch it, add `&` to the command as in `gedit &`.

Comment: when i restarted laptop it was working.By the way thank you very much.

Comment: Did you read what I answered? It explains to you why this happens. If you understand what you did to cause this behaviour, then you will never need to restart to "have it working". If this answer helped, then please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark. If something is not clear, then feel free to signal it here in a comment.

Comment: Its clear.Thank you brother.